# Is there a way to reorder an array by comparing 2 different values and create a new one indicating previousSibling in a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

*UPDATED

This is a basic example of how it should look like:

[image]

Below, is the current way that I got the data from the server.

```
[
    {
        "id": "a2ae04b7-11b3-406f-ab14-3df57a92d01e",
        "title": "#",
        "previousSibling": "af8c3266-4cb0-46f4-ab13-30ba1b1baa3f",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": "af8c3266-4cb0-46f4-ab13-30ba1b1baa3f",
        "title": "#",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "89cb6ed6-a0af-43ee-9c03-c907766e9804",
                "title": "#",
                "parent": "af8c3266-4cb0-46f4-ab13-30ba1b1baa3f",
                "previousSibling": "9b0b1d6f-b055-4d9d-af76-7f6345fcedd0",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": "9b0b1d6f-b055-4d9d-af76-7f6345fcedd0",
                "title": "#",
                "parent": "af8c3266-4cb0-46f4-ab13-30ba1b1baa3f",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fa331d8b-8893-43ba-b2b1-a0824a959f00",
        "title": "#",
        "previousSibling": "a2ae04b7-11b3-406f-ab14-3df57a92d01e",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

I need to reorder based on 2 attributes **id** and **previousSibling**.
This first array comes from the API, and I need to reorder it using **previousSibling** as a reference for the list. So, if the id has the value **02**, the next item of the array that has the attribute **previousSibling** should have the value **02** and so forth.

Currently, I'm able to put the previousSibling of my choice and send it back to the server, however, when I refresh the page with the data, it turns out that it keeps the same position.

Any idea will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it safe to say that the `title` properties have unique values, never the same title used more than once?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the ID should be the unique value and I have a functionality that I can move up or down these items in the screen. This reordering is already working fine, but even after updating this current one I still need to reorder whenever the page loads based on the previous update I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your items with `previousSibling` as a key.
Then loop from the head item looking in the map for the next item:

```js
const orderItems = list => {

  const out = [];

  const headKey = Symbol('head');
  const map = list.reduce((r, item) => (r[item.previousSibling ?? headKey] = item, r), {});

  let next;
  while(next = map[next?.id ?? headKey]){
    out.push(next);
    next.children = orderItems(next.children ?? []);
  }

  return out;

}

console.log(orderItems(list));
```

```html
<script>
const list = [
    {
        "id": "4d7ceda1-2058-479d-b499-8e56913c67e9",
        "title": "text 01",
        children:[
          {
            id: '4d7ceda1-2058-479d-b499-8e56913c6722',
            title: 'child sibling',
            previousSibling: '4d7ceda1-2058-479d-b499-8e56913c67e3'
          },
          {
            id: '4d7ceda1-2058-479d-b499-8e56913c67e3',
            title: 'child item',
            parent: '4d7ceda1-2058-479d-b499-8e56913c67e9'
          },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "c0dabc89-1bf0-4f35-a17b-19adf0126f21",
        "title": "text 02",
        "previousSibling": "cfff0c5f-4339-4767-afce-a0b1526d53cb"
    },
    {
        "id": "cfff0c5f-4339-4767-afce-a0b1526d53cb",
        "title": "text 03",
        "previousSibling": "4d7ceda1-2058-479d-b499-8e56913c67e9"
    },
    {
        "id": "ed9e0ef4-a07b-4483-b5f0-9c5f0d08e0be",
        "title": "text 04",
        "previousSibling": "c0dabc89-1bf0-4f35-a17b-19adf0126f21"
    }, 
]
</script>
```

Comment: Alexander, it worked perfectly! Thank you! Do you think it works for nested lists too? Like a list of children, for example? I did not pass the whole code, just the first level of the array, but in this case, imagine the same structure being used in a new nested children list inside an item, like ``[{id: '01',prevSib: 'xx',children:[{id:'22', prevSib:'yy'}]}...``

Comment: @JulioGraffin did it really? this script's output is different from YOUR expected output... How did it work perfectly?

Comment: @GrafiCode the OP's test data contains a typo/error, but the logic is described good. So I've implemented the described logic and seems everything works nice. It's some task of an answerer to analyze both logic and desired output and deduct.

Comment: @JulioGraffin you could provide the nested data, i'll try to tweak my answer to handle it also

Comment: @GrafiCode It worked, for the first level of the array. Here is just a piece of how it is
``
{
        "id": "0a",
        "title": "test",
        "conditions": "#test",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1b",
                "title": "test",
                "conditions": "#test",
                "parent": "0a",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": "2b",
                "title": "test",
                "conditions": "#test",
                "previousSibling": "1b",
               
            ...
``

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev that's a piece of code I can write down here in comments due to the limit of characters, but is basically the nested part. Let me know if you got this part, ok? I updated the code right at the top. thank you!

Comment: @JulioGraffin will try a bit later

Comment: @JulioGraffin the children come also flat on the first level with a `parent` property?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev no. It should have parent property only if the current one is a child. As for children array, it might be empty or not, just like the example above

Comment: @JulioGraffin  ` { "id": "0a", "title": "test", "conditions": "#test", "children": [ { "id": "1b", "title": "test", "conditions": "#test", "parent": "0a", "children": [] }, { "id": "2b", "title": "test", "conditions": "#test", "previousSibling": "1b", ... ` - is that input data or the desired output?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev [{"id":"00","title":"test","conditions":"#","children":[{"id":"11","title":"test","conditions":"#","parent":"00","children":[]},{"id":"22","title":"test","conditions":"#","parent":"00","previousSibling":"11","children":[]}]},{"id":"01","title":"test","conditions":"#","previousSibling":"00","children":[]},{"id":"02","title":"test","conditions":"#","previousSibling":"01","children":[]}] This one should be the output. As I spoke, the children will have the same aspect as the first level in terms of positioning

Comment: @JulioGraffin ready....

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev it worked fine for level 0. The nested still not working. I updated my post with the output of the current update you've made, and also I put an image with the general idea. thanks!

Comment: @JulioGraffin give your input please in the question

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Updated!

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev it worked like a charm, bro! Thanks a lot!